# Is there any way I can play TradeWars 2002 on modern hardware?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, tradewars-2002

Is there a way to set up a version of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TradeWars_2002) using modern technology, without having to hack up some kind of modem-emulator? Preferably as a multiplayer version, but worst case just to putz with for nostalgia's sake. Or, barring that, where is there a good modem-emulator for OSX (and how do you get it to interface with the game)? :-)

Comment: Wow. I had completely forgotten about that game. Spent many long nights with this; it was a lot of fun.

Comment: TWGS is hosted by gameops. Check out http://www.microblaster.net for a list of servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the game here: [http://eisonline.classictw.com](http://eisonline.classictw.com/).

It looks like you can get a single-player vs AI version or purchase additional licenses to allow remote access:

> To celebrate 25 years of TradeWars, EIS is releasing a special 25th anniversary edition of TWGS. This new release features a free starter package that includes support for one active TradeWars game and a single remote connection.  Practice your trading skills and compete against AI-controlled alien races, explore the editors and create your own custom aliens, planets and ships. The free starter package is fully functional, including all TWGS functionality as well as every TradeWars feature, even the Gold extensions!
>
> If you decide you’d like the flexibility of running more than one game at a time, or you’d like to support more than one remote connection, simply order as many additional game slots ($2 each) and player connections ($3 each) as you need (limit $10 per order). This new pricing model is designed to allow anyone to explore this classic game for free, while continuing to place a premium on large publicly hosted sites.

Comment: is there an open-source version or something? paying per connection is a little weird. do they host it themselves, or is this to be run on one's own server?...

Comment: If you guy it, you have to host it.  I have a game going now with 10 players, it's very rare to have more than 3 on at one time.  The free version will allow one game with one simultaneous connection you'd have to buy a few more connections.  It's pretty cheep.